# PayPal API - How to keep the payment process on my website?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I run a small marketplace with multiple sellers where buyers can buy items and pay with PayPal. The problem is, when someone makes a payment, they are then displayed the "Payment Confirmation" on the PayPal website and are given a choice to either return to their PayPal account, or return to the website.

Is there any way to keep the payment flow on my website, except for the payment part? I notice when buying on Etsy for example, the buyer goes to PayPal to make the payment and is then immediately returned to Etsy for the payment confirmation. They never see the PayPal payment confirmation page.

I assume it could be because Etsy and PayPal have a special arrangement that isn't available to other sites? Or am I missing something in the API?

Right now, with the normal PayPal API, this is what buyers see:

```
NAME, you've just completed your payment.
Your transaction ID for this payment is: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

We'll send a confirmation email to your@email.com

Go to PayPal account overview.
Go back to "seller@email.com".
```

I can't even figure out how to change the "Go back to..." link to my website name in the hidden fields. PayPal just chooses to display the seller's (the person that received the payment) email address.

Is there any way to at least set a website name for them to return to with hidden variables? Keep in mind that I have different sellers, so it's not something I could set inside each seller's PayPal account.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Express Checkout with Set/Get/Do EC API integration. Please check the below document for experience options available with Express Checkout API.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/

The 'useraction=commit' in the PayPal payment auth url triigers the 'Buy' button. If you do not send that request paramter then it will show 'continue' button and you can complete rest of the process on your site.

However, if you are using Paypal Payment Standard product then you need to use Express Checkout to accomplish the outcome you are seeking.